# Attach a new method to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple prototype that I can call on a DIV like this:

```
$('#mydiv').processHtml();
```

This is what I tried:

```
Object.prototype.processHtml = function() {
     var html = this.html();
     // call ajax.... 
}
```

But JavaScript throws as exception that `html()` is not a method.  I tried `HTMLDivElement` instead of `Object` but it didn't help.  Any pointers?

Comment: @AndrewLi thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: Are you trying to define a prototype method for jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the wrong prototype -- you're trying to modify `Object`'s prototype, but you have to modify jQuery's prototype because that's *a jQuery object*, not a JavaScript object. Hence the error, because a regular JavaScript object doesn't have the method `html`.

All jQuery methods are attached to the `fn` property of the jQuery object because the `fn` property is just an alias for the prototype:

```
jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype
```

Thus, to add a method to the prototype of the jQuery object, you have to access the `fn` property (prototype) of the jQuery object, either:

```
jQuery.fn.processHtml = function() {
    ...
}
```

Or the `$`:

```
$.fn.processHtml = function() {
    ...
}
```

This will add the function to the prototype and share the method across all instances of a jQuery object:

```
$(selector).processHtml();
```